# Using angular function into ElementRef/native element

Tags: angular

how to access angular function using elementRef.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {

    let _self = this;
       this.datatable.on('m-datatable--on-layout-updated', function(e){

          $(_self.elRef.nativeElement).find('.deleteFn').click(function(){
          this.router.navigate(['agency/setup']);//like this if using angular

       });
    });
}
```

i want to access the router like above. is it possible? or any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
.click(function(){
```

to the fat arrow syntax:

```
.click(() => {
```

---

```
ngAfterViewInit() {

    let _self = this;
       this.datatable.on('m-datatable--on-layout-updated', (e) =>{

          $(_self.elRef.nativeElement).find('.deleteFn').click(() => {
          this.router.navigate(['agency/setup']);//like this if using angular

       });
    });
}
```

---

Or you might add this as:

```
_self.router.navigate(....);
```

Comment: thank that fat arrow syntax work..but how to get id in angular way? $(this).attr("id") seem not working